# Styling HTML5 default validation notification

Tags: html, validation

How can I style the default validation notification of HTML5 which is shown when "required" attribute is used. I want to change the notification position and show it next to the input field

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<style type="text/css">

input:required:invalid, input:focus:invalid {
background-image: url(/images/invalid.png); //set image
background-position: right top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
input:required:valid {
background-image: url(/images/valid.png);
background-position: right top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

</style>
```